# PHP Undefined offset: 0 while doing string append

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to get this string i.e "C:/xampp/htdocs" , to a separate array which is $url[] in a way that it stores like this

```
$url[0]  ---- > C:/
$url[1]  ---- > C:/xampp
$url[2]  ---- > C:/xampp/htdocs
```

NO matter how big the string is I should be store like this , which I did but I am getting this error below .

can anyone please tell why am I getting this error ?

```
<?php
$directory="C:/xampp/htdocs";

//coverting the string into an array
$arr=explode('/',$directory);

//store the count of the array in $n for looping
$n=count($arr);

//declaring an empty array
$url=[];

$k=0;
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++) {
        $url[$k].=$arr[$j].'/';
    }
    $k++;
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<br>";

print_r($url);


?>
```

The data store in $url array that I am printing with print_r() function is as the way I wanted but can't figured why the error is occurring , anyone has solution?

[output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3GMN.png)

Comment: Describe what you want to do? What is the goal?

Comment: @step yes , please check the post again I edited

Comment: Which of these lines throws that error? What have you tried to check **why** that error occurs?

Comment: @NicoHaase at this line I am getting an error  $url[$k].=$arr[$j].'/';
I tried using the array_fill() function , it did fixed the error but , the output is not anymore the same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$url=[]` just declares an empty array, so that when:

```
   $url[$k].=$arr[$j].'/';
```

is first executed, it is read as:

```
   $url[0]=$url[0].$arr[$j].'/';
```

and `$url[0]` isn't defined.

Use [`array_fill()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to populate the array instead:

```
$url=array_fill(0,$n,'');
```

So the whole code looks like (I've added an extra directory to show why `array_fill` is necessary):

```
<?php
$directory="C:/xampp/htdocs/samples";
$arr=explode('/',$directory);
$n=count($arr);
$url=array_fill(0,$n,'');
$k=0;
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++) {
        $url[$k].=$arr[$j].'/';
    }
    $k++;
}
print_r($url);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:/
    [1] => C:/xampp/
    [2] => C:/xampp/htdocs/
    [3] => C:/xampp/htdocs/samples/
)
```

[Teh Playground!](https://www.tehplayground.com/mpI8HqJdNDzrYcDs)

Comment: it changed the whole output or maybe I am using it in a wrong way , could you please edit the answer and attach the full code?

Comment: Thank you  Now I know where I was making mistake , thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind modifying the original array you could simply append the current value to the previous one.

```
$directory = "C:/xampp/htdocs";
$url = explode('/', $directory);

foreach ($url as $i => $value) {
  if ($i > 0) {
    $url[$i] = $url[$i-1] . '/' . $value;
  }
}
// first index is the only one with trailing slash
$url[0] .= '/';
```

Comment: Wow , Nice , thanks for the solution